# Trying to read entire complex JSON file into SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

So I have a complex JSON file that I want to read into a SQL table.
The below lets me get one record by changing the number in $.events[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AekQf.png).venue

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\test\test.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.events[1].venue')
WITH 
(
[venueName] varchar(20),
[venueId] varchar(20),
[legacyVenueId] varchar(20),
[venueZipCode] varchar(20),
[venueStreet] varchar(50),
[venueCity] varchar(20),
[venueStateCode] varchar(10),
[venueCountryCode] varchar(10)
)
```

[results set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AekQf.png)

I have found answers that say it will work with cross apply but I can't seem to wrap my head around it because I have to go another level deep after I increase the number

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the path to each projected column in the WITH clause of OPENJSON, so (making some assumptions about the structure of the JSON file), something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.events') 
WITH 
(
  [venueName]        varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueName',
  [venueId]          varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueId',
  [legacyVenueId]    varchar(20)  '$.venue.legacyVenueId',
  [venueZipCode]     varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueZipCode',
  [venueStreet]      varchar(50)  '$.venue.venueStreet',
  [venueCity]        varchar(20)  '$.venue.venueCity',
  [venueStateCode]   varchar(10)  '$.venue.venueStateCode',
  [venueCountryCode] varchar(10)  '$.venue.venueCountryCode'
)
```

Comment: This looks correct. Just to add, would recommend the OP review the Microsoft docs on OPENJSON() for more info. Option 2 section on this page I believe answers their question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I cannot believe it was that easy and I'm an idiot - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Should you want a CROSS APPLY version achieving the same thing David's answer does:

```
    SELECT ven.*
    FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.events') ev
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(ev.value,'$.venue')
    WITH 
    (
        [venueName] varchar(20),
        [venueId] varchar(20),
        [legacyVenueId] varchar(20),
        [venueZipCode] varchar(20),
        [venueStreet] varchar(50),
        [venueCity] varchar(20),
        [venueStateCode] varchar(10),
        [venueCountryCode] varchar(10)
    ) ven
```